# Find the power of the matrix representation of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

"The matrix representation of $T:R^2 -> R^2$ in the basis {$\begin{pmatrix}
        1  \\
        1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$, 
$\begin{pmatrix}
        -2  \\
        2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$} is $D =\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & \frac 1 {2} \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

Decide $T^n ( \begin{pmatrix}
        2  \\
        5  \\
        \end{pmatrix})$ for every integer $n>0$."

Isn't $T(x)$ representation of the linear transformation which means that I have: $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & \frac 1 {2} \\
        \end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix}
        2  \\
        5  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$? Or how do I tackle this problem?

Another guess that I have is that I should use that $ A^n = PD^nP^{-1}$ but I don't know if that's applicable here?

Comment: You're right, but can you simplify your answer further?

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to say that 
$$
T^n \pmatrix{2\\5} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & \frac 1 {2} \\
        \end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix}
        2  \\
        5  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
In particular, note that the diagonal matrix is the matrix *with respect to* the basis given.  Instead, note that
$$
\pmatrix{2\\5} = 3.5 \pmatrix{1\\1} + .75  \pmatrix{-2\\2}
$$
and proceed from there.

Comment: So could I say that I have: $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & \frac 1 {2} \\
        \end{pmatrix}^n \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac {7}{2}  \\
        \frac {3}{4}  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @gbgult that is indeed the coordinate vector of your answer... with respect to that same basis.  To put it another way, your answer with respect to the standard basis should be
$$
\pmatrix{1&-2\\1&2} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&\frac 12}^n \pmatrix{\frac 72 \\ \frac 34}
$$

Comment: @gbgult If you want to put all that together, you could say that we have computed the answer (with respect to the standard basis) by computing 
$$
T^n \pmatrix{2\\5} = \pmatrix{1&-2\\1&2} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&\frac 12 }^n \pmatrix{1&-2\\1&2}^{-1} \pmatrix{2\\5}
$$

Comment: Hmm, I'm starting to get it now! What I don't really understand is why do I multiply with $\pmatrix{1&-2\\1&2}$ which gives: $\pmatrix{1&-2\\1&2} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&\frac 12}^n \pmatrix{\frac 72 \\ \frac 34}$. What do I get from doing that? Can't see that intuitively.

Comment: Again, the vector
$$
\pmatrix{\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2} = \pmatrix{ 1 & 0  \\  0 & \frac 1 {2}}^n \pmatrix{\frac 72 \\ \frac 34}
$$
is the coordinate vector of our answer with respect to that basis.  That is, if we were to write the vector with the standard basis, we'd find that we really have
$$
\alpha_1 \pmatrix{1\\1} + \alpha_2 \pmatrix{-2\\2} = \pmatrix{1&-1\\1&2} \pmatrix{\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2}
$$

Comment: Oh, I see, I think my problem now has moved from linear transformation to change of basis to be honest. Because I don't see intuitively why $\pmatrix{1&-1\\1&2}$ would change it back to the standard basis. I'll do some reading on it and see if I get it.

Comment: By the way: regarding formatting, `$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$` is a quicker way to make those matrices.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that when I copied your code :-). I might bump this thread tomorrow by the way if I still need help with that change of basis. Hope that's okay.

Comment: Sure.  If you need help, comment and I'll stop by if I'm at the computer tomorrow.  You may find it more productive, however, to start a new question about changes of basis.